# Spring URL not seen, with controller and mapping

Tags: java, spring

im trying to configure hello world application. The problem is my dispatcherServlet cannot see the URL's.

First thing first the vital code below:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>DebtDetector</display-name>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rootApplicationContext.xml</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param> -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="kaczynski" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.properties"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="kaczynski" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
package kaczynski.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ControllerAccount {


    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String welcomePage(){
        System.out.println("aa");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and given warrning: (after http://localhost:8080/DebtDetector/index)

```
   lip 15, 2016 10:57:13 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DebtDetector/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

full server startup logs:

```
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.32.0
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_51-b16
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Java\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\endorsed
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Java\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Java\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.3.RELEASE;;.
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lip 15, 2016 11:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1452 ms
lip 15, 2016 11:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
lip 15, 2016 11:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
lip 15, 2016 11:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [281] milliseconds.
lip 15, 2016 11:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\DebtDetector.xml
lip 15, 2016 11:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DebtDetector' did not find a matching property.
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:18 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
lip 15, 2016 11:48:18 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate.properties]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
lip 15, 2016 11:48:21 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
lip 15, 2016 11:48:22 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
lip 15, 2016 11:48:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:18 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:18 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5294 ms
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:23 CEST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lip 15, 2016 11:48:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate.properties]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry addEntityManagerFactory
WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:23 CEST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lip 15, 2016 11:48:25 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:48:23 CEST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 2216 ms
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\DebtDetector.xml has finished in 10,289 ms
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11162 ms
lip 15, 2016 11:48:26 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DebtDetector/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Comment: what url do you hit and what is the url you gave in @RequestMapping. Double check.

Comment: Is DebtDetector your application name?

Comment: DebtDetector is the app name. The url i Hit goes: "http://localhost:8080/DebtDetector/index"

Comment: start server, right click -> clean tomcat work directory and retry

Comment: Can you please share your server's startup log , just wanna check whether RequestMappingHandlerMapping is registering `/index` or not , also we can check registered web context.

Comment: Do you have a /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp in your project?

Comment: yes i do have it, the problem is not not there becouse even if i wouldnt the return method would be string but i'd have output in console as sysout is implemented, but im not getting any, so the request is not meeting the controller method at all.

Comment: I am asking this because when I strip the persistence part from your code, it works for me on Tomcat 7. I have these dependencies: commons-logging-1.2.jar, spring-aop-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar and spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar. I modified your web.xml to put the servlet and servlet-mapping elements at the end of web.xml (and old habit from a stricter era...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Defining class-level request handling

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class ControllerAccount {


    public String welcomePage(){
        System.out.println("aa");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

OR Defining method-level GET request handling

```
@Controller
 public class ControllerAccount {

       @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=GET)
        public String welcomePage(){
            System.out.println("aa");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
@Controller
 public class ControllerAccount {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String welcomePage(){
            System.out.println("aa");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```